# 20 panel graphs from ggplot have shifted values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph with 20 panels so as to be able to graph 20 y-values and 1 x-value individually. The x-axis are days of July to October and y-axis values are temperatures for each of the years 1996 to 2015.[image]

The 20 panels that I am getting have shifted temp values for July-October months of each year (see attached and do not show all the 20 years but only for 10 years (1996-2006).[image]

The output of `dput(head(atlanta_temp_data))` is as following

```
structure(list(DAY = structure(c(19539, 19540, 19541, 19542, 19543, 19544), class = "Date"), X1996 = c(98L, 97L, 97L, 90L, 
89L, 93L), X1997 = c(86L, 90L, 93L, 91L, 84L, 84L), X1998 = c(91L, 
88L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 89L), X1999 = c(84L, 82L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 
91L), X2000 = c(89L, 91L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 96L), X2001 = c(84L, 
87L, 87L, 84L, 86L, 87L), X2002 = c(90L, 90L, 87L, 89L, 93L, 
93L), X2003 = c(73L, 81L, 87L, 86L, 80L, 84L), X2004 = c(82L, 
81L, 86L, 88L, 90L, 90L), X2005 = c(91L, 89L, 86L, 86L, 89L, 
82L), X2006 = c(93L, 93L, 93L, 91L, 90L, 81L), X2007 = c(95L, 
85L, 82L, 86L, 88L, 87L), X2008 = c(85L, 87L, 91L, 90L, 88L, 
82L), X2009 = c(95L, 90L, 89L, 91L, 80L, 87L), X2010 = c(87L, 
84L, 83L, 85L, 88L, 89L), X2011 = c(92L, 94L, 95L, 92L, 90L, 
90L), X2012 = c(105L, 93L, 99L, 98L, 100L, 98L), X2013 = c(82L, 
85L, 76L, 77L, 83L, 83L), X2014 = c(90L, 93L, 87L, 84L, 86L, 
87L), X2015 = c(85L, 87L, 79L, 85L, 84L, 84L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please help to fix it.

Following is the R-code that I am using,

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(20)

atlanta_temp_data=read.table("temps.txt",header=TRUE)

atlanta_temp_data$DAY=as.Date(atlanta_temp_data$DAY,format="%d-%b")

class(atlanta_temp_data$DAY)

atlanta_temp_data$Year = rep(1996:2015, each=12)[1:nrow(atlanta_temp_data)]

ggplot(atlanta_temp_data, aes(DAY, group = Year, color = Year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X1996, color = "X1996"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = X1997, color = "X1997")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X1998, color = "X1998")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X1999, color = "X1999")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2000, color = "X2000")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2001, color = "X2001")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2002, color = "X2002")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2003, color = "X2003")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2004, color = "X2004")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2005, color = "X2005")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2006, color = "X2006")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2007, color = "X2007")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2008, color = "X2008")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2009, color = "X2009")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2010, color = "X2010")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2011, color = "X2011")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2012, color = "X2012")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2013, color = "X2013")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2014, color = "X2014")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = X2015, color = "X2015")) +   geom_point(aes(y = X1996, color = "X1996"))+
  geom_point(aes(y = X1997, color = "X1997")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X1998, color = "X1998")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X1999, color = "X1999")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2000, color = "X2000")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X2001, color = "X2001")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2002, color = "X2002")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2003, color = "X2003")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X2004, color = "X2004")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2005, color = "X2005")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2006, color = "X2006")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X2007, color = "X2007")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2008, color = "X2008")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2009, color = "X2009")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X2010, color = "X2010")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2011, color = "X2011")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2012, color = "X2012")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X2013, color = "X2013")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2014, color = "X2014")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = X2015, color = "X2015")) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Year") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle("Atlanta temps for July to October (1996-2015)")+labs(y = "Temperature (degF)")+facet_wrap(~Year)
```

Comment: `facet_wrap(~Year, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: You can also make your life easier if you reshape your data longer so you can plot your lines with one layer instead of separate ones for every year. That'll take care of the legend too.

Comment: `as.Date(atlanta_temp_data$DAY,format="%d-%b")` looks suspect -- what year are you specifying? Does that line and the `Year` line result in data aligned the way you intend?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can make your question reproducible, e.g. by sharing some sample data in the form you're working with. It's often easiest to use the `dput()` function, like `dput(head(atlanta_temp_data))` on the data as you first load it. That will make a text recipe for us to perfectly recreate the first few rows of your data, and see the intended or unintended effects of the subsequent code.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations. I changed the code and used facet_wrap(~Year, scales = "free_x") but now I am seeing following,
- X-axis values in graph for 1996 is only from 2nd july to 12th July. For 1997 is only from July 13th to July 24th, For 1998 is only from July 25th to August 5th and so on
- I am still only seeing graphs from 1996-2006 and missing the graphs from 2007-2015

Comment: Sounds very much like your dates are not being converted as you intend. Happy to help if you can make your question reproducible, otherwise we're just going to be speculating.

Comment: thanks for pointing that. My original dataset had x-axis column of only days and month (ex: 05-JUL) and i tried to convert it into a "date" type. I didn't realize that ```as.Date(atlanta_temp_data$DAY,format="%d-%b")``` would also give it a year. How can i fix it please?

Comment: is there a way to convert the data type of x-column. Right now it is as character. I tried converting it to date type but in that process it is also assigning a year to the x-column. Please help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251640/discussion-between-monu-singh-and-jon-spring).

Comment: Sorry I am new to the reproducible concept. I tried running the dput() function and got the following

> dput(head(atlanta_temp_data))
structure(list(DAY = structure(c(19539, 19540, 19541, 19542,
19543, 19544), class = "Date"), X1996 = c(98L, 97L, 97L, 90L,
89L, 93L), X1997 = c(86L, 90L, 93L, 91L, 84L, 84L), X1998 = c(91L,
88L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 89L), X1999 = c(84L, 82L, 87L, 88L, 90L,
91L), X2000 = c(89L, 91L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 96L), X2001 = c(84L,
87L, 87L, 84L, 86L, 87L), X2002 = c(90L, 90L, 87L, 89L, 93L,
93L), X2003 = c(73L, 81L, 87L, 86L, 80L, 84L), X2004 = c(82L,
81L, 86L, 88L

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text of the dput output you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

[Your data] %>%
 pivot_longer(-DAY) %>%
  mutate(year = parse_number(name)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(DAY, value, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]